# Iterate over RowSetDynaClass in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, iteration

How can I **iterate over an object of RowSetDynaClass using Struts 2 tags**? 
The same can be achieved in Struts 1 by using 'logic:iterate' but how to do this in Struts 2?

I have the following code in Action Class:

```
RowSetDynaClass list = get the list
request.setAttribute("theList", list.getRows());
```

and on the jsp that i forward to from this Action i use the following code:

```
<s:iterator value="theList">
    <s:property value="xyz"/>
</s:iterator>
```

This however does not work. I am using Struts 2 framework. 
So how do i iterate over this list..

Thanks. :)

Comment: i am not sure about `RowSetDynaClass` but there is already an iterator tag which takes collection as a source to iterate over

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: yes there is an <iterator> tag..but it does not work with RowSetDynaClass.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over the `RowSetDynaClass`'s `rows` (JSP EL), `getRows()` (Java):

- [RSDC docs](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/RowSetDynaClass.html)
- [RSDC.getRows() docs](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/RowSetDynaClass.html#getRows%28%29)

API docs are often helpful when trying to understand how to use a class.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the details of my problem. Please let me know if there is a way to solve it. Thanks..

Comment: How are you exposing the list? Is there a public getter called "getTheList"?

Comment: There is no getter available since this list is not a list of any custom object. The list is of DynaClass objects. I am not sure but the iterator should be able to iterate over this by itself as it does in struts 1 using the logic:iterate tag where we specify the type of list by the type attribute. Like
`<logic:iterate id="currentObject" name="theList" type="org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBean">`
Struts2 <iterator> tag on the other hand has no type attribute where we specify the object type. I am not sure how it implements the iteration...

Comment: @pratik Consider reading the S2 iterator tag docs. There needs to be a publicly-accessible getter for either the RSDC or its list for the iterator tag to work. The type of objects in the list is not relevant so long as you access list members in a way compatible with OGNL.